# Simple but hard 2 by 2 system in $x$ and $y$

Tags: diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations, closed-form

Is there a systematic way of solving this system, analytically?

$$\begin{cases}
x \  + \ y^2=11\\
x^2+y\ \ =\ 7\\
\end{cases}
$$

I mean, other than brute-force.

Comment: If you isolate $x$ in the first equation and substitute into the second equation, you get a quartic equation in $y$. Then you could plug everything into the quartic formula (which is ugly, but only uses radicals) and have an answer.

Comment: I am looking for an elementary trick if there exists one. Some kind of a way to avoid quartics.

Comment: Since you add a tag "diophantine", do you mean you want to find solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes, but reals are also ok.

Comment: In the reals, [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%3D7,+x%2By%5E2%3D11) finds four solutions but can't find them algebraically.  Please specify your question.

Comment: Sorry, but this is an algebraic system, which reduces to equation $x+(7-x^2)^2=11.$ And the natural roots of this equation are divisors of the constant term 38.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tagged the question diophantine-equations which implies you are interested in integer solutions.

For those, subtract the equations and factorise to get $(y-x)(x+y-1)=4$. If $x,y$ are integers, then so are $y-x,x+y-1$, so we must have $y-x=1,x+y-1=4$ leading to $x=2,y=3$ or other combinations like $y-x=2,x+y-1=2$ which fail to give solutions. But we have certainly got the only integer solution.

For real solutions there is no choice but the quartic route. You get $(7-x^2)^2+x-11=0$ or $x^4-14x^2+x+38=0$. Suppose you had not already found the $x=2$ solution. Any rational solution $\frac{a}{b}$ must have $b$ a factor of 38 and $a$ a factor of 1 (the coefficient of $x^4)$. So you try $x=2$ and find it is a solution. You now factorise to get: $(x-2)(x^3+2x^2-10x-19)$. You can repeat the process, but trying $x=\pm1,\pm19$ does not give any more solutions. So you have no choice but to use the standard techniques to solve the cubic to get the irrational solutions. It has in fact got three real roots: $3.13131$, $-3.28319$, $-1.84813$.

Comment: Another solution is to add these equations and get $(x+ 1/2)^2 + (y + 1/2)^2 = 37/2$ another equation describing a circle on a plane.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the allowable values of $x,y$.  If they are naturals, clearly $y \gt x$ and it is easy to see $x=2, y=3$ is a solution.  If they are reals, you can do $y^2=11-x$, plug that into the other and get a quartic in $x$ that the rational root theorem finds the solution (among others).  Is that what you mean by brute force?

Comment: Yes. I try to avoid quartic. (I did know the solutions.)

Comment: the other three intersections have $x$ values that are roots of an irreducible cubic, with three real roots. this is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis